# Weird SupportMapFragment behaviour

Tags: android, google-maps, android-ndk, java-native-interface, google-maps-android-api-2

If we use our native library using `System.loadLibrary()` then `SupportMapFragment` just kills `activity` after few seconds when it's launched. And it does that without any stacktrace. This is the best log I could collect:

```
06-10 02:10:01.063 22787-23766/com.myapp.staging E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.staging-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.staging-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myapp.staging-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-10 02:10:01.063 22787-23766/com.myapp.staging W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.myapp.staging rsrc of package com.google.android.gms
06-10 02:10:01.063 22787-23766/com.myapp.staging I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1
06-10 02:10:01.063 22787-23766/com.myapp.staging I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 1
06-10 02:10:01.153 23793-23793/? I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --debuggable --compiler-filter=speed --dex-file=/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000000/DynamiteModulesA_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@user@0@com.google.android.gms@app_chimera@m@00000000@DynamiteModulesA_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk@classes.dex
06-10 02:10:01.153 23793-23793/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@user@0@com.google.android.gms@app_chimera@m@00000000@DynamiteModulesA_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
06-10 02:10:01.153 23793-23793/? I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 721.250us (threads: 4) 
06-10 02:10:01.153 5853-5853/? E/audit: type=1701 msg=audit(1465506601.153:5185): auid=4294967295 uid=10329 gid=10329 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=23766 comm="androidmapsapi-" reason="memory violation" sig=11
06-10 02:10:01.153 3542-4463/? D/libgps: OnGpsExtensionMessage: message_id(1), data(0x7f95455e44), size(2432)
06-10 02:10:01.153 3542-4463/? D/libgps: GpsiHook: API: gpsSvStatusCb(GpsiHookStateGps: e,c,g)
06-10 02:10:01.153 3542-4463/? D/libgps: proxy__gps_sv_status_cb : called
06-10 02:10:01.173 3542-3607/? I/PassiveLocTracker: GPS Satllite Status
06-10 02:10:01.243 3542-4368/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{ae4e596 u0 d0 com.myapp.staging/com.myapp.ui.activity.FrameActivity}
06-10 02:10:01.243 3067-4605/? D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0x7f6bae1f88
06-10 02:10:01.243 3067-4605/? D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0x7f6bae1f88
06-10 02:10:01.243 3542-4286/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 21
06-10 02:10:01.253 3542-4368/? D/InputDispatcher: Focus left window: 22787
06-10 02:10:01.253 3542-4639/? I/AppOps: sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10329 , packageName=com.myapp.staging , type=finishOp
06-10 02:10:01.253 3542-4120/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.myapp.staging (pid 22787)(adj 0) has died(114,1020)
06-10 02:10:01.253 3542-3564/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{6ba02d0 u0 d0 com.myapp.staging/com.myapp.ui.activity.VisitActivity}
06-10 02:10:01.253 3542-4227/? I/AppOps: sendInfoToFLP, code=42 , uid=10329 , packageName=com.myapp.staging , type=finishOp
06-10 02:10:01.263 3542-4120/? D/ActivityManager: isAutoRunBlockedApp:: com.myapp.staging, Auto Run ON
06-10 02:10:01.263 3542-4120/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{6796427 u0 com.myapp.staging/com.myapp.ui.activity.FrameActivity t5324}: app died, no saved state
```

I have spent few days trying to understand what was causing it and it seems if we remove `System.loadLibrary()` call i.e. not use our native lib then `SupportMapFragment` works fine. Is there any way I can resolve it without removing our native lib?

**EDIT:**
I created a sample app to reproduce this issue and after the above mentioned log I also got something which seems useful:

```
06-14 13:17:28.415 5756-5756/? E/audit: type=1701 msg=audit(1465892248.405:4500): auid=4294967295 uid=10332 gid=10332 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=6431 comm="androidmapsapi-" reason="memory violation" sig=11
```

**EDIT2:**

*MapsActivity.java*

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Go.init(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
}

public void showMap(View view) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MapFragment()).commit();
}
}
```

*MapFragment.java*

```
public class MapFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_frag, null, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

*Go.java*

```
public final class Go {
// init loads libgojni.so and starts the runtime.
public static void init(final Context ctx) {
    if (Looper.myLooper() != Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        Log.wtf("Go", "Go.init must be called from main thread (thread="+Thread.currentThread().getName()+")");
    }
    if (running) {
        return;
    }
    running = true;

    // TODO(crawshaw): context.registerComponentCallbacks for runtime.GC

    System.loadLibrary("gojni");
    Go.run(ctx);
    new Thread("GoReceive") {
        public void run() { Seq.receive(); }
    }.start();
}

private static boolean running = false;

private static native void run(Context ctx);
}
```

This is the folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Does updating the Libs help?

Comment: `E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@user@0@com.google.android.gms@app_chimera@m@00000000@DynamiteModulesA_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied`

Comment: @Shark yeah I saw that, but what is it? This log is not coming from my app. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Could you post the code where you are calling `System.loadLibrary` and using `SupportMapFragment`? Could you share the folder structure where you are holding your native library?

Comment: @antonio Just updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are issues logged in gmaps-api-issues regarding memory leaks and the latest is [issue 8596](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8596). And tracing back to other related issues, this has been fixed in recent version of the Google Maps Android API as mentioned in [issue 4766](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4766), however, same issue was still encountered on other versions.

In addition to that, [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment) also mentioned about memory leak caused when holding on to objects beyond the view's life as the view cannot be released.

And, this SO post - [Google Maps Android API v2 SupportMapFragment memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523949/google-maps-android-api-v2-supportmapfragment-memory-leak) might also help.

Comment: Yeah I am already using the workaround of disabling location in `onDestroy()` by calling `setMyLocationEnabled(false)`. This also has nothing to do with the issue that I am facing because the memory leak only happen when finishing activity.